# How can I remove white space in regex findall?

Tags: python, regex

I want to find the string after specific string.

```py
phrase = "100% (good day for the birthday)"
result = re.findall(r'(?<=for)(.*)[\w]+', phrase)
```

result,

```
[' birthda']
```

how can I remove first space and have whole words?

Comment: @ArkistarvhKltzuonstev Do you know why last charaster is truncated?

Comment: I think you have your capturing group on wrong place and make it non-greedy also `result = re.findall(r'(?<=for).*?(\w+)', phrase)`

Comment: `re.findall(r'\bfor(?:\s+the)?\s+(\w+)', phrase)`. The last char is truncated because `.*` grabs all text to the end, and `\w+` grabs the last char taking it off the `.*` matched text.

Comment: @jayko03 Did that work out?

Answer (score 0):

You match the first space because you assert what is on the left is `for` and the `.` will also match a space.

You don't match the last char because the `[\w]+` expects at least a single word char to match, and this match is not part of the capturing group.

---

If you want to remove the first space, you can match it after `for`

To match only word characters separated by a single space, you could match 1+ word chars and repeat that preceded by a space and capture the whole match in the capturing group.

```
\bfor (\w+(?: \w+)*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qls0qH/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/LpFSIc)

If you want to use the `.*` you could add matching a word character after it but **note** that it can match any other char except a newline in between

```
\bfor (.*\w)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SmKPGl/1)